# Using `arcpy.Exists()` and `arcpy.Delete_management` on a temporary layer

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, delete

Suppose I make a temporary layer from a feature class in a gdb:

```
select = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("roads", "select_lyr", "FIPS_CODE = '06023'")
```

Later I want to see if that layer exists and if it does, delete it.

```
try:
    if arcpy.Exists(select):
        arcpy.Delete_management(select)
    else:
        print "select doesn't exist" 
except:
    pass
```

In this scenario, nothing happens. Assuming the layer gets deleted automatically , the `print` statement doesn't print, and if I just type `>>> select` in the console, I get a `<Result Object>`. What am I doing wrong here?! Do I even need to delete this (say I am creating hundreds of similar `selects` and I don't want it to run out of memory)? Do I need to add the `arcpy.en.workspace = 'roads'` or something before the delete?

Comment: You have deleted the layer in memory but not the variable, so now it points to nothing, it should be enough to del select and let python clean up the memory.

Comment: Why is it in a bare `try/except` block?  You're throwing away the error messages you need to diagnose the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `select` is a [results](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/result.htm) object.

```
>>> lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management ("roads", "layer")
>>> type (lyr)
<class 'arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjects.Result'>
```

Use the layer name instead.

```
try:
    if arcpy.Exists("layer"):
        arcpy.Delete_management("layer")
    else:
        print "select doesn't exist" 
except:
    pass
```

Comment: To compliment this answer - I see this problem all the time, people treat result objects as if they are the output. I would go as far to say make it *crystal clear* and instead of calling the result object lyr (which in my opinion indicates its a layer object) call it something like `resObj` or even `result`.

Comment: @Hornbydd, that's made even more confusing by the fact that using the result object as the input into another function works totally fine in most cases, since the string representation is usually the path to the output dataset.  But obviously that can be dangerous as shown here since it's not totally consistent.  I actually use that behavior quite often since it saves a bit of typing when creating temporary feature classes and whatnot